# Remove *.bak files from ido-mode minibuffer

Tags: ido

I am using `ido-mode` to select files from Emacs. This works well for most cases, but for some cases I would like to modify the files that are shown in the completion buffer with `ido-find-file`.

In some folders I have a lot of `*.bak` files, and I would like to have the possiblity to remove them from the completion buffer by pressing the <kbd>F1</kbd> key, for example. This is how far I got on this task:

```
(add-hook 'ido-minibuffer-setup-hook 'ido-my-keys)

(defun ido-my-keys ()
  (define-key ido-file-completion-map (kbd "<f1>") 'my-modify-files))

(defun my-modify-files ()
  (interactive)
  (message-box "Here I would like to delete the .bak files from the minibuffer"))
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ido-mode` has built-in support for hiding files matching specific regexps. All you need to do is add `\.bak` to `ido-ignore-files`:

```el
(add-to-list 'ido-ignore-files "\.bak")
```

After invoking `ido-find-file`, you can then hit <kbd>C-a</kbd> (`ido-toggle-ignore`) to toggle hiding of `.bak` files.

Comment: Perfect! It works like a charm :)

Comment: @HåkonHægland Great! :) If you're interested, have a look at the documentation of `ido-find-file` (`C-h f` `ido-find-file` `RET`) for a full list of commands and options you can toggle while the Ido prompt is active.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to ignore files by extension for file name completion purposes is using the variable `completion-ignored-extensions`. The variable holds a list of strict suffix strings that are ignored for:

- directory completion, if the list element ends in a `/`, or
- file completion otherwise.

The `ido-ignore-files` variable, on the other hand, is a list of regular expressions, and matches anywhere in the file name, unless the regex is anchored. In particular, [the  recommendation in another answer](//emacs.stackexchange.com/a/3483/8543),

```el
(add-to-list 'ido-ignore-files "\.bak")
```

tells Ido to match the substring `.bak` *anywhere* in file name, which may or may not be what you really want. On the other hand,

```el
(add-to-list 'completion-ignored-extensions ".bak")
```

makes all Emacs completion machinery, not only Ido, but also out-of-the-box file completion and Dired, and likely other places, ignore files ending in `.bak` (including full name match). Note that this variable is not a list of regexes, but rather a list of literal suffixes; the dot should not be `\`-escaped.

The default `completion-ignored-extensions` list contains commonly ignored suffixes such as `.elc`, `.o`, `.a`, `.so`, `~`, `.git/`, and many more. This is why the default `ido-ignore-files` list is *suspiciously short*.

The completion behavior is actually more complex than just always ignoring the files; see the docstring of the variable. One important point is that if *all* completions are to be ignored according to `completion-ignored-extensions`, then *none are*. This allows, for example, descending into the `.git/` subdirectory: as soon as it becomes the only completion (after typing `.g/`, if no other directories matching `.g*/` exist), it is shown by Ido as a possible completion. Similarly, in the original question case, typing `.bak` makes Emacs "un-ignore" and immediately show files ending in `.bak`, unless other non-ignored files match by Ido rules, so that the <kbd>C-a</kbd> is not always necessary to find an ignored file.